# How to set a variable to self(class) in swift class? ios xcode

Tags: ios, swift

I have a class called Node. When I initialize Node, I want its previous node and next node to always point to itself- makes a circulating-endless string of nodes.

```
class Node {
    var name: String!
    var previousNode: Node = self // error 
    var nextNode: Node = self     // error

    init?(name: String) {
        if name.isEmpty {
            return nil
        }
        self.name = name
    }

    func setPreviousNode(prevNode: Node) {
        self.previousNode = prevNode
    }

    func setNextNode(nextNode: Node) {
        self.nextNode = nextNode
    }
}
```

How can I automatically assign a variable to **self** in class?

Comment: Can't you do it on init method? It would have the same result

Comment: @Joonp you can write it in viewDidLoad method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot refer to `self` until all of self’s properties are initialized, you have to take a two-phase approach and use `init` – but you also need to make the nodes optional, since you’ll need to set them to something first (e.g. `nil`) and then set them to self again after all self’s properties (including them) have been set.

You could take the same approach as you’re using with `name` and make them implicitly optional for convenience later, so long as you’re careful to ensure they’ll never be `nil`.

```
class Node {
    var name: String!
    var previousNode: Node!
    var nextNode: Node!

    init?(name: String) {
        if name.isEmpty {
            return nil
        }
        self.name = name
        previousNode = self
        previousNode = self
    }

    // since this takes a `Node` not a `Node?` you know
    // it can’t set them to nil, which is good
    func setPreviousNode(prevNode: Node) {
        self.previousNode = prevNode
    }

    func setNextNode(nextNode: Node) {
        self.nextNode = nextNode
    }
}

let node = Node(name: "fred")  
// good to know the playground printing code checks for cycles!
// {name "fred" {name "fred" {…} nil} nil}
```

Comment: I see. thank you. it helped me understand swift a little better!